# Break grid using label on JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, calendar, label

I am trying to design a really simplified calendar app using JavaFX. Currently, I can display events that last for one hour since they perfectly fit my grid pane. However, if this event lasts for longer than an hour, I cannot make the labels occupy half of the next grid:
[1.5 hour event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPDyL.png)

As it can be observed on the image, I can just display events of only 1 hour. How can I make thoese labels "longer"? Thank you for your help! This is the code I use to show my labels!

```
        Label newLabel = new Label(labelText);
        newLabel.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", CLASS_LABEL_TEXT_SIZE));
        newLabel.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
        newLabel.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        newLabel.setMaxHeight(2000);
        newLabel.setMaxWidth(2000);
```

Comment: I'm not a JavaFX expert but since you're not defining the size of the label directly it seems to be handled by the grid - which makes sense. So if you want to support smaller units like 30 or even 15 minute slots you'll probably have to either do the positioning and sizing yourself or break the grid into smaller units.

Comment: Define the grid so the height of each cell represents the smallest acceptable time, for example, half-hour.  Use [rowspan](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#add-javafx.scene.Node-int-int-int-int-) to define how many rows an event occupies. 1-hour event should occupy 2 rows. 1.5 hours event should occupy 3. For more halp post [mre]